# How many main story missions are in Metal Gear Solid 5: TPP?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, how many main missions are in the game? I have reached mission 50. I don't know if I am finished though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### 41 unique story missions in total (Mission list in spoiler below) and 157 Side Ops.

> **Mission 1** Phantom Limbs
>   **Mission 2** Flashback Diamond Dogs
>   **Mission 3** A Heros Way
>   **Mission 4** C2W
>   **Mission 5** Over the Fence
>   **Mission 6** Where Do the Bees Sleep
>   **Mission 7** Red Brass
>   **Mission 8** Occupation Forces
>   **Mission 9** Backup Back Down
>   **Mission 10** Angel With Broken Wings
>   **Mission 11** Cloaked in Silence
>   **Mission 12** Hellbound
>   **Mission 13** Pitch Dark
>   **Mission 14** Lingua Franca
>   **Mission 15** Footprints of Phantoms
>   **Mission 16** Traitors Caravan
>   **Mission 17** Rescue the Intel Agents
>   **Mission 18** Blood Runs Deep
>   **Mission 19** On the Trail
>   **Mission 20** Voices
>   **Mission 21** The War Economy
>   **Mission 22** Retake the Platform
>   **Mission 23** The White Mamba
>   **Mission 24** Close Contact
>   **Mission 25** Aim True Ye Vengeful
>   **Mission 26** Hunting Down
>   **Mission 27** Root Cause
>   **Mission 28** Code Talker
>   **Mission 29** Metallic Archaea
>   **Mission 30** Skull Face
>   **Mission 31** Sahelanthropus
>   **Mission 32** To Know Too Much
>   **Mission 38** Extraordinary
>   **Mission 41** Proxy War Without End
>   **Mission 43** Shining Lights, Even In Death
>   **Mission 45** A Quiet Exit
>   **Mission 46** Truth: The Man Who Sold the World
>   **Mission 47** The War Economy
>   **Mission 48** Code Talker
>   **Mission 49** Occupation Forces
>   **Mission 50** ST-84 Sahelanthropus Boss Fight
>   <del>**Mission 51** Kingdom of Flies</del>

Comment: So why are 33-37, 39, 40, 42, and 44 missing from this list? Why is 51 crossed out?

Comment: @DanHenderson The list above is unique missions, the missing ones are replays of existing missions. 51 was planned but cut from the final game.